# How do i get an incoming HTTP request's FULL URI as a string in python?

Tags: python-3.7

Language: python 3.7

Preface: i'm absolutely brand new to coding, as well as setting up servers, and whatnot. please go easy on me, as things that may be commonplace to 5 year old programmers, are completely foreign concepts to me.

I'm trying to build a twitch chat bot that runs locally. It needs to use oauth2 to allow the bot to take actions on the twitch users behalf. First, you have to send the twitch user to a site, and when they log into their twitch, they get redirected. I've got it set to redirect them to 127.0.0.1, and when it does that, it actually redirects them to "127.0.0.1/bunchofinformation"

I'm directing the user to a site, they're authorizing the python script on the site, and then its redirecting the user back to the script. I'm getting the request from the web browser, but i need to get the entire URL as a string, because it's redirecting the user to 127.0.0.1/bunchofinformation.
With the code i have, it will tell me im getting a request from 127.0.0.1, but i can't figure out how to get that full URL, which i need to pass to a variable later

Ive dug through the docs of the all the libraries im using, and i just can't find a way to get the FULL url as a string.It's currently just telling me the incoming request is from 127.0.0.1, and if i remove the .strip() function, it gives me a lot more information including web browser type, but still leaves the url at 127.0.0.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm available to answer any questions.

```
import requests
import webbrowser
import http.server
import socketserver
import socket
import urllib.request

class MyTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self): # handle() method will be called once per connection

        print("Recieved one request from {}".format(self.client_address[0]))

        msg = self.rfile.read().strip()

        print("Data Recieved from client is:".format(msg))

        print(msg)

webbrowser.open("website.i.need.them.to.visit")

PORT = 80

Handler = MyTCPRequestHandler 


with socketserver.TCPServer(("127.0.0.1", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.handle_request()
```

Comment: I am not actually sure about your problem. If I understood a bit, you are trying to implement a webservice. Then, take a look at Flask package. If not, please, clarify your question.

Comment: Howdy. thanks for popping in to answer. I'm trying to build a twitch chat bot that runs locally. It needs to use oauth2 to allow the bot to take actions on the twitch users behalf. First, you have to send the twitch user to a site, and when they log into their twitch, they get redirected. I've got it set to redirect them to 127.0.0.1, and when it does that, it actually redirects them to "127.0.0.1/authorization-code-I-need". With the code i have, it will tell me im getting a request from 127.0.0.1, but i can't figure out how to get that full URL, which i need to pass to a variable later.

Comment: Please, don't add such information in the comments section. Instead, enhance your question, which is the first thing people see.

Comment: Thank you for that information.